# Rvest scraping multiple data in one function

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-parsing, rvest

I know how to loop when a page is paginated, but I wish to scrape multiple information/`html_nodes` in one loop function, but I am not sure if you can set it up. So far I have tried the following. It's basically a jobsearch website, where I want company name, company description and number of open positions.

I use `sprintf` to get page 1-14.

```
urlingtek <- sprintf("https://www.jobindex.dk/virksomhedsoversigt/kanal/ingenioer?page=%d", 1:14)
```

I have made a loop, which works to scrape one data source.

```
company <- function(virksomhed){
  company %>% read_html() %>% 
      html_nodes('.jix_company_name_link a') %>% 
      html_text()
}
virk <- lapply(urlingtek, virksomhed)
```

But I wish to scrape all the utilities down at once if possible.

I have so far tried using

```
jobvirksom <- function(alt){
    alt %>% 
        read_html() %>% 
        html_nodes('.jix_company_name_link a') %>% 
        html_text()
    html_nodes('.jix_companyindex_overview_ad_content') %>% 
        html_text()
    html_nodes('.jix_active a') %>% 
        html_text()
}
```

So far without any luck. Would be a lot better if I could scrape it all at once, press `lapply` and turn into one list.

Comment: You're not passing data to two of your `html_nodes` calls in your function. Also check out `purrr::map_df`, which makes assembling multiple fields into a data.frame easier.

Comment: So putting alt%>%read_html infront Of The last html_nodes should fix it?

Comment: Probably not, because it looks like you want to pass the same thing into the second and third `html_nodes` calls. More likely you need to save the result of the first pipeline to a variable and pass that into the others, or use `lapply`/`purrr::map` to iterate over the first node set, find each of the parts of it you're trying to extract, and assemble them into a list or data.frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the start of a solution.  In this case with only 14 webpages to parse through it is sometimes easier to just use a loop.  With this number of pages the time between a for loop and lapply is insignificant.

I notice the web pages are not consistently formatted so this solution will need additional work when the data is missing or inconsistent.  This will work for the first 2 pages and fail on the third where the overview is missing.

```
library(rvest)
urlingtek <- sprintf("https://www.jobindex.dk/virksomhedsoversigt/kanal/ingenioer?page=%d", 1:14)

#define empty data frame to store all data
alllistings<-data.frame()

for (i in urlingtek){
  print(i)
  #read the page just once
  page<-read_html(i)

  #parse company name
  company<-page%>%html_nodes('.jix_company_name_link a') %>% html_text()
  #remove blank company names
  company<-trimws(company)
  company<-company[nchar(company)>1]
 #parse company overview
  overv<-page %>% html_nodes('.jix_companyindex_overview_ad_content') %>% 
  html_text()
  #parse active information
  active<-page %>% html_nodes('.jix_active a') %>%  html_text()

  #create temporary dataframe to store data from this loop
  tempdf<-data.frame(company, overv, active)
  #combine temp with all data
  alllistings<-rbind(alllistings, tempdf)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I see the issue when hitting the companies without descriptions. When running them one by one, it wasn't an issue because I merged and sliced my way out of it. But this code definitely give me a way around and something to work with.